# unable to redirect a path using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

in the .htaccess I have added the following

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 302 ^/contact\.html$                  /contact-us
```

www.example.com/contact.html redirects to www.example.com/contact-us.php?q=contact.html

i need to redirect www.example.com/contact.html to www.example.com/contact-us.php?1=contact.html

Comment: Your browser cached your previous 301 redirects. Don't use 301 unless you are production ready. Use 302 redirect when debugging.

Comment: hi @emix can you send it as answer?

Comment: No, it's a typo. Please delete this question.

Comment: hi @emix, do you mean RedirectMatch 302 instead of RedirectMatch 301 ?

Comment: Yes, always do that, change to 301 when you are sure it's working fine.

Comment: Are you trying something like this? `RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/contact\.html$ /www.example.com/contact-us.php?q=contact.html [R=301,NE,NC,L]`, again testing using R=302